# How to FInd Week Commence date (Monday) From WeekNumber and Year TSQL

Tags: t-sql

Hi I have a requirement where I have been Given the total counts of calls for a Week , for a year .

```
          Week    Year        TotalCalls
           1      2015          34567
           2      2015          345353
```

I want to add a weekCommence Date and Month Into this data. COuld anyone please advice how/if I can achieve this with the data available ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the startingdate of the current week you can use this formula:

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) MondayOfCurrentWeek
```

So, if you table has a CallDateTime field, your query could be:

```
select datepart(wk, CallDateTime) as Week, 
datepart(day, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, CallDateTime), 0) ) WeekMonday,
datepart(day, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, CallDateTime), 0) ) WeekMonth,
datepart(year, CallDateTime) as Year, 
count(*) as TotalCalls
from CallTable
group by datepart(wk, CallDateTime), 
datepart(day, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, CallDateTime), 0) ),
datepart(day, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, CallDateTime), 0) ),
datepart(year, CallDateTime)
```